# VBA Merging two strings excluding overlap part

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to merge two strings but when end of `s1` is the same as beginning of `s2` do not repeat that part of the string? For example:

```
s1 = "The quick "          s2 = "brown fox"       -> "The quick brown fox"
s1 = "The quick brown fox" s2 = "quick brown fox" -> "The quick brown fox"
s1 = "The quick brown "    s2 = "quick brown fox" -> "The quick brown fox"
s1 = "The quick brown fox" s2 = ""                -> "The quick brown fox"
s1 = ""                    s2 = "fox"             -> "fox"
```

Comment: Do you really need a VBA solution? You can achieve it by a formula

Comment: Yes. We can help best if you show any code you have already tried. For me, in a VBA solution, I would probably loop character by character and compare each string. But please show your code.

Comment: @Sgdva: would be curious about such formula.

Comment: @FunThomas My bad I didn't see the 3rd scenario, you really need to loop through the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a simple formula, but you can write a rather simple function. You could use it in your code or as a UDF in an Excel sheet.

The code loops over the length of the second string and compares if the left part of the second string is equal to to right part of the first string.

```
Function mergeString(s1 As String, s2 As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Len(s2) To 1 Step -1
        If Left(s2, i) = Right(s1, i) Then
            mergeString = s1 & Mid(s2, i + 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    ' Nothing matches
    mergeString = s1 & s2
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, I'll add a formula:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=@LET(X,LEN(A1),Y,SEQUENCE(X),Z,MID(A1,Y,X),SORT(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(Z&"*",B1),0)=1,LEFT(A1,X-LEN(Z)),A1)))&B1
```

Comment: Am I guessing only available on O365?

Comment: @Sgdva, I suppose we can rework this to fit earlier versions with some little tricks however it would become rather long and tedious. Maybe someone else can come up with a much cleaner formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

[image]

**Code**

```
Sub Exec_StringCheck()
Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "The quick ": s2 = "brown fox"
    Debug.Print Return_TxtMerged(s1, s2, " ")
    s1 = "The quick brown fox": s2 = "quick brown fox"
    Debug.Print Return_TxtMerged(s1, s2, " ")
    s1 = "The quick brown ": s2 = "quick brown fox"
    Debug.Print Return_TxtMerged(s1, s2, " ")
    s1 = "The quick brown fox": s2 = ""
    Debug.Print Return_TxtMerged(s1, s2, " ")
    s1 = "": s2 = "fox"
    Debug.Print Return_TxtMerged(s1, s2, " ")
End Sub
Function Return_TxtMerged(TxtOneToMerge As String, TxtTwoToMerge As String, TxtDelimiter As String)
Dim CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge As Long
Dim ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge As Variant: ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge = Split(TxtTwoToMerge, TxtDelimiter)
Dim TxtDummy As String
    For CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge = 0 To UBound(ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge)
    If InStr(TxtOneToMerge, CStr(ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge(CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge))) = 0 Then ' 1. InStr(TxtOneToMerge, CStr(ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge(CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge))) = 0
    TxtDummy = IIf(TxtDummy = "", CStr(ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge(CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge)), TxtDummy & TxtDelimiter & CStr(ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge(CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge)))
    End If ' 1. InStr(TxtOneToMerge, CStr(ArrVarTxtTwoToMerge(CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge))) = 0
    Next CounterArrTxtTwoToMerge
    Return_TxtMerged = TxtOneToMerge & TxtDummy
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using O365, then you may apply any one of the approaches as well,

**FORMULA APPROACH ONE: In Cell C1**

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",,TRIM(A1:B1))," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")))
```

**FORMULA APPROACH TWO: In Cell D1**

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1&" "&B1," ",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1:Z1)*99-98,100)),1))
```

[image: FORMULA APPROACH]

Comment: A headsup, but I'm afraid this is not always going to work. What would happen if the s1 was 'The quick brown fox jumped ' and s2 was 'over the slow black sheep'. The options currently rely on unique words.